# Centering asserts in struktogramm using struktex

Tags: diagrams, struktex

I'm currently using [struktex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/struktex) for generating structograms (Nassi–Shneiderman diagram).

My source code looks as follows:

```
\begin{struktogramm}(150,45)
\assign{Do something}
\ifthenelse{5}{5} {Make a decision?}{Yes}{No}
    \ifthenelse{3}{3} {Make a decision?}{Yes}{No}
        \assign{Do something}
        \change
        \assign{Do something}
    \ifend
    \change
    \assign{Do something}
\ifend
\end{struktogramm}
```

which results in this simple diagram:

[image]

Actually I'm missing two things:

1. Is it possible to center the contents (i.e. "Do something") within each cell?
2. How can I avoid the empty set symbol by spanning the cell "Do something" over two rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, I took Harish's answer a step further to solve #2:  Add a `\rule`.  Manual tweaking is required to guess the height of the rule.  But in my edit, I realized I could also achieve the centering with symmetric `\hfill`s about the entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{struktex}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\sub}{}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
  \begin{struktogramm}(150,45)
\assign{\mbox{}\hfil Do something}
\ifthenelse{5}{5} {Make a decision?}{Yes}{No}
    \ifthenelse{3}{3} {Make a decision?}{Yes}{No}
        \assign{\hfill Do something\hfill}
        \change
        \assign{\hfill Do something\hfill}
    \ifend
    \change
    \assign{\hfill Do something\rule[-4.7ex]{0ex}{10.3ex}\hfill}
\ifend
\end{struktogramm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easiest (may be ugliest) is to use

```
\mbox{}\hfil Do something
```

You can also use `\null` instead of `\mbox{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{struktex}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\sub}{}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
  \begin{struktogramm}(150,45)
\assign{\mbox{}\hfil Do something}
\ifthenelse{5}{5} {Make a decision?}{Yes}{No}
    \ifthenelse{3}{3} {Make a decision?}{Yes}{No}
        \assign{\mbox{}\hfil Do something}
        \change
        \assign{\mbox{}\hfil Do something}
    \ifend
    \change
    \assign{\mbox{}\hfil Do something}
\ifend
\end{struktogramm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea about 2.

Comment: Big thanks for your solution @Harish Kumar. I've decided to mark Stevens answer as correct because of his lower reputation. My mistake to ask two questions at once :-)

Comment: @Daniel Oh Noooo...! ;)